# upload photo using the FileOpenPicker windows8.1

Tags: c#, image, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1

I'm trying to upload photo to my application  using the FileOpenPicker and when I write the following code:

```
FileOpenPicker open = new FileOpenPicker();
open.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
open.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

// Filter to include a sample subset of file types
open.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

// Open a stream for the selected file
StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync();

// ImageSource im = (new Uri (file.Path));
ChildPic.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));
```

it did not give me an error but the Image control is left blank.

there is value in the Path: C:\Users\Pictures\New folder(15).jpg

Comment: Put a break point in `ChildPic.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(file.Path));` Check whether there is any path value or not.
Let us know what it giving..

Comment: there is value in the Path:   C:\Users\Pictures\New folder\(15).jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new BitmapImage(Uri)` will not work with any path. It supports only `URI` having protocol `http`, `ms-appx`, `ms-appdata`. You have to use stream.

```csharp
FileOpenPicker open = new FileOpenPicker();
open.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
open.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;

// Filter to include a sample subset of file types
open.FileTypeFilter.Clear();
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".bmp");
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".png");
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpeg");
open.FileTypeFilter.Add(".jpg");

// Open a stream for the selected file
StorageFile file = await open.PickSingleFileAsync();

// ImageSource im = (new Uri (file.Path));
var bmp = new BitmapImage();
using (var strm = await file.OpenReadAsync())
{
    bmp.SetSource(strm);
    ChildPic.Source = bmp;
}
```